# Deploying report in Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2014 with xml datasource

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I have a report in Visual Studio 2013 that is connected to a datasource of xml.
When trying to deploy the SSRS I'm getting this message:

> An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'XML' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services

Comment: Is your Sql Server express edition?

Comment: Hi,No, this is the full infomation :Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      12.0.2269.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.10240.16384
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.10240.16384
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.10240

Comment: what does this query return for you - 
`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition`

Comment: Express Edition (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

The reason I asked for the edition information because there are few limitations, not all editions of SQL Server can be used to host the database. And it seems from Books Online that `Express Edition` has those limitations.

SQL Server Express only supports Datasources located in the Local SQL Server instance.

Few links you can go through for more/detailed information -

[Link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx#Reporting)

[Link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: is there a way to pass a table that is made from struct on winforms to ssrs?